# How to match a list to another in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

**Table 1**

| Name | Surname |
| --- | --- |
| Mike Senior | Smith |
| Sami Albert | Loris |
| Alfred Tony | Rene |
| Peter | Flore |
| Mike Junior | Peterson |
| Richard Smith | Verna |

**Table 2**

| Data | Surname |
| --- | --- |
| Barber mike senior | Cell 2 |
| lawyer Alfred tony | Cell 4 |
| chef richard smith | Cell 6 |

How can I find the correct surnames in Cell 2, Cell 4, Cell 6??

I tried vlookup but it needs an exact match.. it didn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always have to extract the first word of the second table you can do this REGEXEXTRACT:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E," (.+)")
```

Then, with Proper you can set them to have the first letter as capitals and insert them in VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(PROPER(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E," (.+)")),A:B,2,0))
```

And, finally, you can use them as an array if you want:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(PROPER(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E," (.+)")),A:B,2,0)))
```

[image]